# Manipulating a vector and seeing the result of the changes in a different class

Tags: c++, string, pointers, templates, vector

I have a class like so:

```
template<typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type>
class MyClass {

private:

    std::vector<C>myOwnVectors;

public:

    auto add(const C& addedContainer) {

        myOwnVectors.push_back(addedContainer);
    }

    void displayMyContent() {
        for (C j : myOwnVectors) {
            for (T i : j) {
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to pass any (single) kind of STL container to MyClass.add(). These containers will be added to a vector of such containers within MyClass called myOwnVectors.
MyClass.displayMyContent() loops through the vector and displays the complete content off all added containers one after the other.

This so far works. However, if I do this in main:

```
MyClass<std::string, char> first;
std::string bi("Bing");
std::string bo("Bong");
first.add(bi);
first.add(bo);
bi[1] = 'o';
bo.push_back('g');

const MyClass<std::string, char> second = first;

first.displayMyContent();
```

First of all I cannot call displayMyContent on second because of:

> `the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "MyClass<C,T>::displayMyContent[with C=std::string,T=char]" object type is: const MyClass<std::string,char>"`

And then, calling displayMyContent on first does not reflect the changes I have made to bi and bo. It only prints the originally added values. I want them to reflect the changes. I understand my code might need major changes, but I wanted to portray what my intention is as accurately as possible. I have tried pretty much all pointer / reference / value / const reference..etc. combinations I could think of to no avail. At this point I'm doubting if it is even possible to do such a thing.

Comment: The first problem is you need to mark the display function as const (also that function is doing needless copies of containers, the for loop should likely be `for (const C& j : myOwnVectors)` (this is also true of the inner loop btw). Your second problem is your vector is storing copies of wtv you passed in so modifications in main wont be reflected, you would need to store pointers (or std::reference_wrappers) but if you do that you need to be *very careful* about your lifetimes.

Comment: @OP Is this a case of assuming that C++ works similar to other languages that automatically uses reference-based semantics?  If so, C++ doesn't work this way.  C++ is value-based, meaning that copies will be made by default (passing parameters, returning values, etc.), and not references to the actual object instance.  In C++, you must explicitly state you want to use reference semantics (as mentioned you need `for (const C& j : myOwnVector)`

Comment: @Borgleader that comment should be posted as an answer instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didnt because while i can point out the problem i dont exactly have a clean solution for the lifetime issue and to me that is critical. I can only point out that it is something to look out for.

Comment: @Borgleader - Yes I have thought about storing pointers, but then if I add elements to the vectors in main, wouldn't there be a possibility that the vector (e.g. Bing in this case) gets moved in memory, and then my pointer in MyClass would point to the wrong memory location?

Comment: Is there even a way to store references / pointers in a class to outside vectors where there is no possibility of some kind of memory failure and changes to the vectors get reflected inside the class?

Comment: @TheHootsman The memory pointed *to* by the vector may change on reallocation (due to push_back, etc), but the vector itself doesnt. That said, disclaimer about lifetimes still applies (unless you go shared_ptr route).

Comment: @TheHootsman yes, if you store pointers/references to individual vector elements, and then the vector reallocates its inner array or moves the elements around, the pointers/references will become invalid. One way to avoid that would be to store a pointer/reference to the vector itself, and then use indexes to its elements.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you for the help! (this applies to Borgleader too)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution with pointers. As was suggested by others, your member vector must store pointers of any type, because `bi` and `bo` are objects, which the vector knows nothing about.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    private:
        std::vector<T*> myOwnVectors;
    
    public:
        void add(T* addedContainer)
        {
            myOwnVectors.push_back(addedContainer);
        }
    
        void displayMyContent() const
        {
            for (auto *j : myOwnVectors)
            {
                for (auto &&i : *j)
                {
                    std::cout << i << " ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<std::string> first;
    std::string bi("Bing");
    std::string bo("Bong");
    first.add(&bi);
    first.add(&bo);
    bi[1] = 'a';
    bo.push_back('g');
    
    const MyClass<std::string> second = first;
    first.displayMyContent();
}
```

Online code here: https://rextester.com/IPZF36993

Unfortunately, the memory of `bi` and `bo` is not automatically managed by the vector. Your only option to would be to use shared pointers. Here's an example of such problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    private:
        std::vector<T*> myOwnVectors;
    
    public:
        void add(T* addedContainer)
        {
            myOwnVectors.push_back(addedContainer);
        }
    
        void displayMyContent() const
        {
            for (auto *j : myOwnVectors)
            {
                for (auto &&i : *j)
                {
                    std::cout << i << " ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

template<typename T>
void problem(T &my_class_)
{
    std::string be("Bend");
    my_class_.add(&be);
    be.push_back('y');
    my_class_.displayMyContent(); // ok here
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<std::string> first;
    std::string bi("Bing");
    std::string bo("Bong");
    first.add(&bi);
    first.add(&bo);
    bi[1] = 'a';
    bo.push_back('g');

    problem(first);
    
    first.displayMyContent(); //oops!
}
```

Online code here: https://rextester.com/WYA69962

My advice would be to revisit this design so that the vector stores the actual data. If you want other classes to read the vector you can provide a getter function that returns a `const &`. Hope this helps.